# Ansible: what role path does a collection use?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install some software (pulp) with Ansible. The actual installer comes in an Ansible collection, which in turn depends on a downloaded role (geerlingguy.postgresql).

The role is installed, and I can access it from one of my own playbooks. But when the tasks in the pulp.pulp_installer try to access the geerlingguy.postgresql role, they can't find it.

I followed the instructions on the [Pulp Web site](https://pulpproject.org/ansible-installer/), which says to install the geerlingguy.postgresql role just like any other role with

```
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.postgresql
```

Specifically, when I try to run the installer, I get this error message:

```
ERROR! the role 'geerlingguy.postgresql' was not found in pulp.pulp_installer:ansible.builtin

The error appears to be in '/home/kkeane/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/pulp/pulp_installer/roles/pulp_database/tasks/install_postgres.yml': line 130, column 15, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

I installed the geerlingguy.postgresql role into the standard ~/.ansible location:

```
tree -L 3 ~/.ansible/
/home/kkeane/.ansible/
├── collections
│   └── ansible_collections
│       ├── ansible
│       ├── community
│       └── pulp
├── cp
├── galaxy_token
├── roles
│   └── geerlingguy.postgresql
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── defaults
│       ├── handlers
│       ├── meta
│       ├── molecule
│       ├── tasks
│       ├── templates
│       └── vars
└── tmp
```

I can also access the role directly from one of my own playbooks.

The error message suggests that Ansible is only looking inside the pulp.pulp_installer and ansible.builtin collections, instead of using my full role path.

Do collections in fact use a different role path? If so, how do I get it to find the geerlingguy.postgresql role?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was due to a bug in the specific version of Ansible that I used (2.9.6). Based on comparing the source code, version 2.9.19 seems to have this issue fixed. Unfortunately, on my version of Ubuntu (20.04), the latest version of Ansible is 2.9.6, and even the Ansible ppa does not have a newer version of the 2.9 series.

So I had to update to Ansible 2.10. That process is as follows. Note that you must use the package name ansible-base; if you install the package ansible, you will just reinstall the broken version.

Keep in mind that upgrading to 2.10 may have other side effects; there were substantial changes to Ansible between 2.9 and 2.10.

```
apt remove --purge --auto-remove ansible
add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
apt-get update
apt install ansible-base
```

Edit: there may be a possibility to install 2.9.19 on Ubuntu, after all, using pip instead of apt.